# Android: NSD service still available after closing app

Tags: android

i have a problem with Androids NSD.

I registered a service using NsdManager on device A. With an other device B in the same WiFi i started the app "bonjour browser" which was able to discover the service. Fine. 
But when i closed the app which registered my service on device A, the service is still available on the other device B using "bonjour browser". I killed the app and still the service is available. When i disable the wifi connection of device A the service disappears on device B. But when i reconnect to the wifi WITHOUT starting the service registration app, the services pops up again. Strange.

Is this normal? Do i need to explicit un-register the service? I thought that the service should disappear as soon as my app (and the NsdManager) is not working anymore.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem when using NSD on Android.

Your app should explicitly un-register the service before exiting.

Comment: But what if the app crashes? How do I clean up the NSD services?